# Accessing private functions and variables in a public class from another class

Tags: vb.net

As the title says, I've run into a problem where I have to call certain private functions in a class.

```
Public Class Class1
private Type
Private Name
private Function()
```

I have tried doing the following:

```
Public Class Class1
  Dim copyClass As Class1
  Public Shared Instance As Class1

  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    copyClass = Me
  End Function
  Public Function createInstance() As Class1
    Instance = copyClass
    Return Instance
  End Function
```

Then in my other class, Class2, I have added:

```
  Public Property callingObject As wdCopyPatch
    Get
      Return copyObject
    End Get
    Set(value As wdCopyPatch)
      copyObject = value
    End Set
  End Property
```

now, I can just do the following from within a function in Class1

```
Dim Ob as Class2
Ob.callingObject = createInstance()
```

This allows me to use copyObject from Class2 but only gives me access to Class1's Public Functions and variables. What can I do to be able to access Class1's Private functions and variables without making everything public?

Any advice or comments are appreciated :)

Comment: The whole idea of a "private" decelration si to make it private...
As you did with your 2nd class, you need to create properties in your first class, that when set, can call one of its internal functions, and return something through the property

Comment: Remember, you can do "work" in a property's "set" and "get" methods...

Comment: if you need access to some private fields and functions, *why* are they private?

Comment: Code was initially written and my "Class2" was really just a set of functions. My project is to clean up this code, but Class2 heavily depends on Class1. It makes sense for them to be private, but I guess the way I'm trying to "clean up" the code does not make sense.

Comment: maybe one one should be a private internal class the "parent" uses as a helper.  Then, the internal class could be used as needed, but the functions not exposed to the rest of the world.

Comment: I like that idea; It would be great if you could provide a small example, though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comments, here's some code:

`Sandbox` is my class with a private function, and a public property getting info from that private function.

`otherclass`, calls this property of sandbox.

```
Public Class sandbox

    Public ReadOnly Property myHiddenValue() As String
        Get
            Return get_that_sucker()
        End Get

    End Property

    Private Function get_that_sucker()
        Return "boo!"
    End Function

End Class

Public Class otherClass

    Public Sub mySub()
        Dim mysandbox As New sandbox
        MsgBox(mysandbox.myHiddenValue)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: As for the private functions, is there any way I can use them for my instance of Class1?

Comment: Private functions can be used "inside" its parent... so any other functions inside class1, can use the private functions (in) class1.

Comment: So, would be be acceptable to use public functions to call **some** private functions?

Comment: I would do it thorugh a property, like my code in the answer above. If your public function, calling your private function, turns out to be exactly the same thing.. then you actually have a public function :-)

Private functions are there not to be used out of context of their parent instantiation... for instance, a property, may call 3 different private functions, get some infor form them, re-work that, and provide an output... that is where you would use private functions, that should not be called directly from "outside"

Comment: No probs, feel free to get more clarification if you need to.